# How to start Django server that is located in another machine

Tags: django, ftp, webserver

For business matters i've moved my local server to enterprise's server for doing some tests but i don't know how to start/stop server via local, i guess it's launching via python runserver... but i don't know how to do it with the files allocated in another machine.

Regards!

Comment: You ssh to it and run it from shell?

Comment: please rephrase. as it stands your question does not make much sense. Have you tried to ssh to the remote machine and run `manage.py runserver` there?

Comment: ssh has to be activated in remote machine, isn't it?

Comment: yes, on the remote machine must be started ssh daemon (for linux), also see fabric http://docs.fabfile.org/

Comment: still asking for a rephrase. what does local server mean? your development machine? is it properly deployed (you don't run manage.py runserver normally in a production environment) so please fill us in a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to a remote machine, activate virtualenv , python manage.py runserver serverip:port . That's all. Also check that your port is not closed by firewall.